# Java Setting variable zero to beging another game, but not working

Tags: java

I have written some codes for a game. The game will toss three coins at the same time: a quarter, a dime and a nickel. If a head appears on any of the coins, you win the facevalue of the coin. For example, if the toss resulted in heads for the quarter, heads for the dime and tails for the nickel, you will get: 25 cents plus 10 cents, for a total of 30 cents for the first round. The game will keep on tossing until the total wins get to $1 or the last toss resulted in total wins more than $1.

I have a question to ask the player if he wants to play the game again. But this part does not seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

I have suspect, the part of the code causing the problem is the variable to keep the running score totalRoundWins. I set it to zero for the beginning of the new game, but it does not seem to be working.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner Class
import java.util.Random; // for the random class

/*
This is a tossing coins for a dollar game
*/
public class oldCoinDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String play; // To ask the player if he wants to play the game. 
        // Calling the method to decsribe the game
        gameDescription();
        // Asking the player if he wants to play the game.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to play the game? Choose y for Yes and n for No: ");
        play = keyboard.nextLine();
        // calling the method to start the game 
        startingGame(play);
    }

    public static void gameDescription() {
        System.out
                .println("This is a tossing coins for a dollar game. The game will toss three coins at the same time: a quarter, a dime and a nickel.");
        System.out
                .println("\nIf a head appears on any of the coins, you win the facevalue of the coin. For example, if the toss resulted in heads for ");
        System.out
                .println("the quarter, heads for the dime and tails for the nickel, you will get: 25 cents plus 10 cents, for a total of 30 cents for the first round");
        System.out.println("\nThe game will keep on tossing until the total wins get to $1 or the last toss resulted in total wins more than $1");
        System.out.println("If the total wins is exactly $1, you win $1 otherwise you win nothing.");
        System.out.println("\nIt will cost you to 1 cent to play the game");
    }

    public static void startingGame(String play) {
        String again = "y"; // To ask the player whether he wants to play the game again after the first round
        String quarterSide; // to get the quarter side for the wins
        String dimeSide; // to get the sime side for the wins  
        String nickelSide; // to get the nickelSide for the wins
        double wager = 1; // to calculate the wager for each game
        double totalWager = 0; // to get the total wager if the player decides to play the game multiple times
        double winsQuarter = 0; // To get the quarter wins after each round of toss
        double winsDime = 0; // To get the dime wins after each round of toss
        double winsNickel = 0; // To get the nickel wins after each round of toss
        double totalRoundWins = 0; // Accumulator for total wins each round of toss
        double totalGameWins = 0; // Accumulator for total wins if player plays multiple games 
        char stop = ' '; // to stop the game if the first time total wins is equal to 1 or greater than 1 
        // Creating three instances of the coin class
        Coin quarter = new Coin();
        Coin dime = new Coin();
        Coin nickel = new Coin();
        if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                do {
                    // Toss the coins
                    quarter.toss();
                    dime.toss();
                    nickel.toss();
                    if (quarter.getSideUp().charAt(0) == 'h')
                        winsQuarter = 25;
                    else
                        winsQuarter = 0;
                    if (dime.getSideUp().charAt(0) == 'h')
                        winsDime = 10;
                    else
                        winsDime = 0;
                    if (nickel.getSideUp().charAt(0) == 'h')
                        winsNickel = 5;
                    else
                        winsNickel = 0;
                    totalRoundWins += (winsQuarter + winsDime + winsNickel);
                    if (totalRoundWins == 100 || totalRoundWins > 100) stop = 's';
                } while (stop != 's');
                if (totalRoundWins == 100) {
                    totalGameWins++;
                    System.out.println("\nCongratulations! You have just won $1.00");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\nSorry you did not win");
                    System.out.println("The total winnings from this round is: $" + totalRoundWins);
                }
                // Getting the total wager for playing multiple times 
                totalWager += wager;
                // to clear total round wins for another game. 
                totalRoundWins = 0;
                // Asking the player if he wants to play the game.
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to play the game again? Each Game would Cost you 1 cent. Choose y for Yes and n for No: ");
                again = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.printf("Your total wins from the game is: $" + "%.2f", totalGameWins);
            System.out.printf("\nYour total wager for the game is: $" + "%.2f", totalWager / 100.0);
            System.out.println("\nThank you for playing the game. Goodbye!");
        } else if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This sounds like it might be homework

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Yes, it is a homework. I just can't figure out, why when the player chooses to play the game again, the do-while part does not go through all the iterations, it just does the coins once and stop. So the statement in the while part of the do-while is always true after the first round.

Comment: Think of how the do while works, what is the condition that makes it keep going and where does this condition change and when should it be reset if necessary

Comment: It will only iterate 2-4 times from what I see. You're adding the total of all coins (25 + 10 + 5 at most) to the number of roundWins. Instead of doing 100 rounds, its waiting until youve gotten a total of $1

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
     // Toss the coins
     quarter.toss();
     dime.toss();
     nickel.toss();

     if (quarter.getSideUp().charAt(0) == 'h')
          winsQuarter = 25;
     else
          winsQuarter = 0;
      if (dime.getSideUp().charAt(0) == 'h')
           winsDime = 10;
      else
            winsDime = 0;

      if (nickel.getSideUp().charAt(0) == 'h')
           winsNickel = 5;
      else
           winsNickel = 0;

      totalRoundWins += (winsQuarter + winsDime + winsNickel);
      if (totalRoundWins == 100 || totalRoundWins > 100) stop = 's';
} while (stop != 's');
```

Take a look at that. You initialize the `winDime` and what not when its heads. Lets say they all land heads, thats 25 + 10 + 5, total of 40. 3 games of all heads, and thats a total of 120. Instead of saying `totalRoundWins++`, you are adding the total value of the win to it.

To solve this:

```
int roundWins = 0;
int totalAmount = 0;
int quarterAmount = 0;
int dimeAmount = 0;
int nickleAmount = 0;
char stop = ' ';

while(stop != 's') {
     do {
          tossCoins();

          if(quarter == heads)
               quarterAmount += 25;
          if(dime == heads)
               dimeAmount += 10;
          if(nickle == heads)
                nickleAmount += 5;

          totalAmount += quarterAmount + dimeAmount + nickleAmount;
     }while(totalAmount < 100);

     quarterAmount = 0;
     dimeAmount = 0;
     nickleAmount = 0;
     roundWins++;
     if(roundWins == 100) stop = 's';
}
```

Comment: Hi Vince, I have a question about this part of your code:                       roundWins++;
if(roundWins == 100) stop = 's';

Comment: Once a quarter, dime, or nickel come up heads, they stay heads.  You never reset the amounts to zero when they come up tails in your revised code.

Comment: This is just to give an idea of how the structure should b. thanks for the heads up about setting the amounts back to 0. As for the coins never being reset from heads, they will "reset" once we toss the coins again.

Comment: Thank you guys, your discussion about initialization prompted me to take a look at the variables that needed to be initialized after the do-while loop, and I found that not only would I have to initialize totalRoundWin, I have to also initialize stop = ' '.

Comment: @user3486062 chars, such as stop, can be represented as integers (you can actually do `if(stop == 7)`). By default, ints and chars are 0 when not inialized. Although they have defaults, you might get compiler errors if you try checking a value before it gets initialized. For example, if you did `char stop; if(stop == 0)` you would get an error, because stop hasnt been initialized yet. But, if you did initialize at some point before checking it, you wont get an error.